# vue-socket.io socketio is not defined

Tags: socket.io, vue.js

I'm trying to use vue-socket.io package here, so I did install it first then imported it in the app.js file, but in the Vue.use line the socketio throws a console error Uncaught ReferenceError: socketio is not defined:

```
npm install vue-socket.io --save

import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio('http://localhost:3000'), store);
```

Comment: That package appears to depend on https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client.

Comment: I think this is an alternative way to include the file using the script tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io) suggests a default configuration.

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://socketserver.com:1923');
```

If you want to use the one you're using

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio('http://localhost:3000'), store);
```

You're going to have to import `socketio` from somewhere. Your script doesn't know what that is. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/blob/master/src/Observer.js) suggests that you could do this:

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'

Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio('http://localhost:3000'), store);
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'll give it a try